# Design: storing id in redis while data content in mysql

Tags: mysql, schema, redis

I am using redis data types to do some data aggregation based on the id of a specified object. To fetch the information of the object, a select query on mysql database has to be done each time. Since the data is originally stored in mysql database. I am wondering whether this hurts performance and this is a proper implementation.

Comment: Looks like you want to use Redis as a cache. Try referring to [The Little Redis Book](http://openmymind.net/redis.pdf) by Karl Seguin for some design patterns. Particularly, refer to chapter #3—Leveraging data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because redis is a in memory database you can use it as cache, as you described.

You'll get more performance "hurts" from mysql rather than redis. We're using redis to store sets with ids of documents stored in MongoDB. We keep track of recents documents, more votted, etc and redis is great for this.

Use batch operations, a good schema and redis is great.